# What's the value of the ratio $\frac{r}{PH}$ in the figure below?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference:  In the figure, find $\frac{r}{PH}$

[image]

My progress.

I found that the figure represents the Pappus chain.[Pappus Chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus_chain)

therefore :

The height $h_n$ of the center of the $n_th$ circle above the base diameter $ACB$ equals $n$ times $d_n$.
$\therefore PH=4.2r \implies \frac{r}{PH}=\frac{r}{4r}=\frac{1}{4}$

Is this resolution correct?
Is there another alternative for the resolution?

Comment: Given the other questions you've been asking, have you tried using pythagorean theorem to prove it? (Yes, it will take some work, so show what you've tried)  (I'm also guessing you don't understand the inversion approach that is used to give the one-liner proof.)

Comment: It is some work but you can solve it the same way you solved the last problem.